# Server permissions issue, I can't upload files anymore in wordpress

Tags: linux, wordpress, permissions, ssh

So, I changed with chown owner of my wordpress directory to nobody(nobody runs apache)... Now I can automatically update in the dashboard and edit the files, but I can't upload anything else via FTP.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Assign yourself to the group that the files belong to.

For example, if your web files are owned by `nobody` and assigned to the group `webgroup` and your ftp user is `finaldestiny` then you would run the command `usermod -a -G webgroup finaldestiny`

You also need to make sure the folder and files are writable by the group, not just the owner. You can `chmod -R g+w webroot` to add write permissions to all files and folder in the webroot for the group.